# Php Array of arrays get id from name

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the following in PHP:

```
$my_array = array();
$my_array[] = array("id"=>"myid1", "name"=>"myname1");
$my_array[] = array("id"=>"otherid", "name"=>"othername");
$my_array[] = array("id"=>"morestuffid", "name"=>"morestuffname");
```

Having a "name" like "othername", is it possible to retrieve the respective "id" from $my_array without a for loop?

Comment: `array_walk()` maybe `array_map()`?

Comment: do you want to retrieve the id only for othername or for the respective ids for all the names in the array?

Comment: do you have reasons to avoid using `foreach`?

Comment: I want to retrieve the id for the respective name. Note: There are no repeated elements.

Comment: @kekit, you can do that using `foreach` and `break`. So why do you want to avoid using the loop?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov just do not want to be reinventing the wheel, if there is some bultin function to do this. I am learning PHP and try to write code in the best way.

Comment: @kekit, you won't, because there is no built-in function for this (very simple) operation.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov someone came with an answer. Not a built in function yeahh, but is definitely more elegant than a for loop with a break. And I will perform this operation various times.

Comment: @kekit, do you really think it's elegant? It makes 2 loops instead of 1, at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get your array column `name` by `array_column` method.Then find you want string by `array_search` its will return the index of array.

```
$index = array_search("othername",array_column($my_array,"name"));
var_dump($my_array[$index]["id"]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Much more elegant than a for loop. That's what I was looking for. Kudos.

Comment: @kekit, I doubt you'll find it elegant when you'll look at your code after a couple of months. This code is also inefficient, as takes at least 2 loops.

Comment: @kekit, also, `array_column` generates an extra array

Comment: Maybe you're right. However, I tested both approaches and checked the time in miliseconds, in php7 and the results are really similar, something like 1,...xE^-5 ... 
sometimes a method is faster, sometimes it is the other, but found no hegemony or significant difference. I'm always open to brainstorming... :)

Comment: You saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
$id = array_filter( 
        array_map(
            function($array) {
                if($array['name']== 'othername'){
                    return $array['id']; 
                }
            },$my_array
        )
    ); 
print "<pre>";print_r($id);
```